# Error while trying to convert string into date and format it

Tags: business-objects

I'm trying to convert the string into date and format it using the below command in Webi report.

Sample field value = 20200223150301

Below is the formula being used.

```
= FormatDate(ToDate([Kn Credit Status].[Credit Check Date];"yyyyMMddhhmmss");"yyyymmdd")
```

[image: Error shown in report]

Comment: Check your data format returning from the [Kn Credit Status].[Credit Check Date]

Answer (score 0):

Try "HH" for the hours since they are in 24-hour format and "MM" for the month; "mm" is the minutes.

```
=FormatDate(ToDate([Credit Check Date]; "yyyyMMddHHmmss"); "yyyyMMdd")
```

[image]

Here's how you can find all of the FormatDate options...

- Navigate to the FormatDate() function in the center function list
  in the Variable Editor.
- Click on the "More on this function." link in
  the lower right corner.
- Click on the "Custom formats" link in the
  Related Information section at the bottom of the page.

You can also click on this [link](https://blogs.sap.com/2013/11/21/how-to-use-formulae-to-change-date-and-time-formats-in-webintelligence/), but that link could go dead.